# How to handle display of optional BIRT parameters on a report?

Tags: parameters, reporting, birt

I have an optional (multi select) list box parameter in my report. When the parameter is populated, I would like to display the filter conditions in a dynamic text box on my final report.
How do I meaningfully test the parameter value to see if it is populated within the dynamic text box?
I've tried combinations of

```
if(params["Encoding"].value == null {
""
}
else
{
params["Encoding"].value
}
```

but have had no luck.

I've tried testing for null and just testing .value by itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script contains a syntax error.

And usually the easiest way to check if a *string* variable `x` is not empty (or null or undefined) is to just use `if (x)`. If you need a boolean value (e.g. for a visibility expression), you can use `!x` which returns `true` if `x` is empty or null or undefined or `!!x` which returns `true` if `x` is not empty.
Be sure to know the difference between `truthy` and `true` in Javascript.

If your parameter allows multiple values, then its value is a Java array.
You can use the individual objects like this, e.g. to show the values in a dynamic text item:

```
var p = params["Encoding"].value;
var len = p.length;
var out = ["p.length=" + len];
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    out.push("[" + i + "]=" + p[i]);
}
out.join("\n")
```